# fixed header adds space to header

Tags: html, css, header, navigation

Alright, so I had my header the size and design I want it and decided to make it a fixed header. but whenever I do position: fixed; it adds some padding it seems like to the bottom of the header. i can't seem to figure out how to get rid of it.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>FatHead | Blog</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,500,600,700,800|Muli:400,300italic,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <h1 id="logo-large">FAT</h1> <h1 id="logo-small">HEAD</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
   </div>
 </div>
<div class="main-content">
   </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/***********************************
          LOGO
***********************************/

.header{
background-color: skyblue;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width: 100%;


}

.logo{
text-align: left;
display: block;
margin:0 15px 15px 15px;

}

#logo-large{
display: inline;
font-size: 3em;
font-weight: 200%;
font-family: 'Dosis' , sans-serif;
}

#logo-small{
display: inline;
font-weight:0;
font-size: 2.5em;
font-family: 'Dosis' ,sans-serif;
}


/************************************
           NAVIGATION
************************************/

nav ul{
list-style-type:none;
}

nav{
display:inline;
float: right;
}

nav ul li{
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px 0px;
margin: 0;

}

nav ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
padding:20px 12px 12px 12px;
color:black;
font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.25em;

}

nav ul li a:active, nav ul li a:hover{
background-color: deepskyblue;
color: white;
}



/*************************************
           main content
*************************************/




body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure no spaces before or after the tags.

Answer (score 0):

It's the logo margin that is giving that problem.
Here fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xh4e49ta/

```
.logo{
text-align: left;
display: block;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see the difference:

The NL trailing each image adds space between the images, whereas serializing on one line will allow the desired effect of the margin and padding controls

```
<style type="text/css">
  .foo   {margin:0px; padding:0px; width:100px;}
</style>
<div>
<img class="foo" src="../Images/Karon.jpg" />
<img class="foo" src="../Images/Karon.jpg" />
<img class="foo" src="../Images/Karon.jpg" />
<img class="foo" src="../Images/Karon.jpg" />
</div>

<div><img class="foo" src="../Images/Karon.jpg" /><img class="foo" src="../Images/Karon.jpg" /><img class="foo" src="../Images/Karon.jpg" /><img class="foo" src="../Images/Karon.jpg" /></div>
```